# What does only `namespace` mean in this situation?

Tags: php, namespaces

Seeing this line in PHP from [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php), I am not sure what it does:

```
namespace {
  //...
  }
```

Is it similar to wrapping some code in an anonymous function in javascript? What's it purpose?

Note: I know how to normally use namespaces, I just don't understand this, since it looks like a namespace but without any *name* in it and, for me so far, without any purpose.

Comment: I think it's something to do with forcing it to be in the root of all PHP name spaces `/`

Comment: It is an empty namespace which means it is global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It declares the code to be in the global namespace. The purpose of this is that later on in the file there are two functions implemented in a private namespace, and PHP requires that if any namespace is used in the file the first keyword in the file must be `namespace`. So to mix global and namespaced code in the same file, this is how it needs to look.

See https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/commit/88911e6abebb324cca88f546f04d6e71ce778bd3 for the particular commit.

Answer (score 0):

That definition is to ensure that the file containing it loads in the *global namespace*. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1256330/2200058)

```
namespace // empty namespace means global
{
    // Ensure everything you put here belongs the global namespace
}
```

But, **technically** speaking, it is exactly **the same** as not declaring any namespace at all. In both cases everything in it will belong to the *global namespace*.