# Is it possible to replace a function in php (such as mail) and make it do something else?

Tags: php, function

I want to rewrite a function in PHP (let's say the mail() function), and want to make it so when I call mail() from now on, it will load my version of mail() and not the default php version. Is this possible in php?

The reason I want to do this is because I have thousands of lines of code which call mail() and I don't want to rewrite all of them.

Also for future reference, in computer programming, what is it called when you do something like this?

Comment: Python is very good at this, fyi.  PHP is not.

Comment: @gahooa He's trying to avoid refactoring code, I doubt he's going to rewrite it all in Python to make the refactoring easer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to replace (monkeypatch) PHP functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530649/is-it-possible-to-replace-monkeypatch-php-functions)

Comment: Excellent answer in Duplicate-marked topic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is an extension that allows you to override functions. It is meant to be used for debugging, but I guess you can use it for your needs. Take a look:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php

If you wish to call the original function within your version, make sure you read this comment:
[http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php#50821](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php#50821)

Comment: This seems simpler to do than runkit.

Comment: Your links are dead :-(

Answer (score 10):

What you're referring to is generally called [method overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overloading).

While not generally supported by PHP, you actually **may be able to redefine** internal functions (as well as user functions) using [`runkit_function_remove()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-remove.php) or [`runkit_function_redefine()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php). Of course to use that, you'll need to have pretty much full control over the PHP installation - since it's not bundled with PHP you'll need to [install the runkit extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/runkit.installation.php).

Again, **in a normal situation internal functions** as well as user functions **cannot be redefined** (or overloaded) in PHP. This situation illustrates the benefit of wrapping some internal functions with a user function.

Comment: lesson learned. Do you know if there is a reason php does not overload? It seems like a useful tool.

Comment: +1 for runkit over APD. APD seemed a lot more clunky (you have to make a couple of hacks if you want to call the old function from the overload, or if you want to monkeypatch more than one function) - and it seemed APD messes up the exit code from the php process, which means it causes build failures in the situation you might want to use it (overriding things like mt_rand() and time() in a phpunit test case running uder, say, Ant from Jenkins). https://github.com/zenovich/runkit is an update for more recent PHP versions.

Comment: @Tim, It's not overloading. It's overriding.

Answer (score 2):

It's called function overloading and is not possible in **native** PHP but possible using the extensions outlined in the other answers. The PHP documentation claims it is not possible at all: [source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) which is incorrect.

Comment: @ewan Halfway down the page, "PHP does not support function overloading, nor is it possible to undefine or redefine previously-declared functions."

Comment: Tim. Right, that's the bit that needs to be edited.  See Milan's answer and your own.

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use regexps to replace the function name in your files. What app you use is up to you, but I'd recommend the ovely-pricey [Powergrep](http://www.powergrep.com/) (unless you won't need it again).

replace

```
   (\s+)mail([\s(]+)
```

to

```
   $1new_function_name$2
```

and

```
   ^mail([\s(]+)
```

to

```
   new_function_name$1
```

Sorry for my regexp-fu, I don't know how to search for either spaces OR begining of line in one expression.

Comment: I think this will get most of them `(^|\t|\s|\{)mail\s*\((.*?)\)` That will match at the start of the line, a tab or a space or an opening curly brace if its tight to a code block. You will need to add the space back in front of the new function name on replacement. Also if your code blocks start with something other than an opening curly brace { you will need to replace that in the regex match.

Comment: @nickfox: the ones I wrote are what I used in an extremely messy production source so it's field tested and not based on assumption.

Comment: @Raveren, This seems to be avoiding the question rather than answering it.

Comment: It's a viable workaround that solves the problem the asker is having.