# Redefine Built in PHP Functions

Tags: php

I would like to redefine certain functions in PHP that are already built for example, echo() or time() - I don't need to define these functions globally, just  within a single script for testing.

I think this can be done in Perl but in PHP - Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to replace a function in php (such as mail) and make it do something else?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837184/is-it-possible-to-replace-a-function-in-php-such-as-mail-and-make-it-do-someth)

Comment: ... [Is it possible to replace (monkeypatch) PHP functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/530649/), [Php redefine Class Methods OR Class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/137006/)

Comment: ... why would someone do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> [runkit_function_redefine](https://www.php.net/runkit_function_redefine)  — Replace a function definition with a  new implementation

**Note:** By default, only userspace functions may be removed, renamed, or

> modified. In order to override
> internal functions, you must enable
> the runkit.internal_override setting
> in php.ini.

Comment: Does this have a global effect on all PHP scripts, or is this specific to a particular script?

Comment: Editing the php.ini file will affect all PHP scripts running on that particular installation of PHP. The function redifinition itself, however, is exclusive to the scripts that call `runkit_function_redefine()`.

Comment: +1 for runkit - APD is a bit clunky, and it messes up the process exit code, which is going to break using it in test cases. I use the runkit at https://github.com/zenovich/runkit to intercept mt_rand() and time() in test cases, and I'm a happy camper.

Comment: Besides testing purposes, does Runkit is a valable solution for a production environnment ?

I would like to use it with a solution I can not modify to permits back-office users to preview their front office in the future by rewriting time() and any other function related. Should I stop thinking at Runkit and begin to rewrite most classes of the product ?

Comment: @ChrisNash, Happy camper... meaning?

Comment: @JBreton, I believe the purpose of runkit is meant to fix bugs within PHP itself. Making it easy to "patch" a flawed functionality. It doubles up as a stopgap solution for testing purposes too.

Answer (score 6):

You might also want to check out

[`override_function()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) — Overrides built-in functions

from the [Advanced PHP debugger](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.apd.php) package.

Having to redefine native PHP functions or language statements should ring an alarm bell though. This should not be part of your production code in my opinion, unless you are writing a debugger or similar tool.

Another option would be to use http://antecedent.github.io/patchwork

> Patchwork is a PHP library that makes it possible to redefine user-defined functions and methods at runtime, loosely replicating the functionality `runkit_function_redefine` in pure PHP 5.3 code, which, among other things, enables you to replace static and private methods with test doubles.

The latter doesn't work for native functions though

Comment: @Gordon - thanks for the suggestion. I just want to do this for testing purposes and not production code - you are right it does ring alarm bells!

Answer (score 1):

`echo` is not a function, it's a language construct. I don't have anything for that.

But function calls like `time()` can be overridden since [PHP-5.3's namespace fallback policy](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php):

> For functions […], PHP will fall back to global functions […] if a namespaced function […] does not exist.

E.g. for the unqualified function call `time()` in the non global namespace `foo` you can provide `foo\time()`.

Personally I'm using this to mock e.g. `time()` for unit test. I published those mocks in the library [PHP-Mock](https://github.com/php-mock/php-mock-phpunit):

```
namespace foo;

use phpmock\phpunit\PHPMock;

class FooTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    use PHPMock;

    public function testBar()
    {
        $time = $this->getFunctionMock(__NAMESPACE__, "time");
        $time->expects($this->once())->willReturn(3);
        $this->assertEquals(3, time());
    }
}
```