# Stub PHP native methods

Tags: php, phpunit, native, mocking, stub

In my unit test, i'm looking to stub the behaviour of php's inbuilt file_get_contents() method.

Is there a way to stub native methods in PHP (such as file_get_contents() or print_r()) and the likes?

Comment: This question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326835/redefine-built-in-php-functions

Answer (score 3):

If by "stub" you mean replace, there is a PHP [override_function](https://www.php.net/override_function) function; it's part of PECL though. You can also [rename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php) them.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with [runkit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php). Use runkit_function_copy and runkit_function_redefine functions to copy and redefine functions. You should set the runkit.internal_override ini-setting to 1 in order to modify internal functions.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't clear about what 'stub' means.

Do you mean getting doc for functions, like:

```
/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.1.0)<br/>
 * Sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php
 * @param timezone_identifier string <p>
 * The timezone identifier, like UTC or
 * Europe/Lisbon. The list of valid identifiers is
 * available in the .
 * </p>
 * @return bool This function returns false if the
 * timezone_identifier isn't valid, or true
 * otherwise.
 */
function date_default_timezone_set ($timezone_identifier) {}
```

?

Comment: A `stub` is a stand-in for a method. You usually use it in UnitTests: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mocking-the-filesystem and is a technical term: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity; yes, I refer to the wikipedia definition of a method stub i.e. a standin for a method, which i'm looking to use in my unit test.

Answer (score 0):

Since [PHP-5.3's namespace fallback policy](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php) you can override calls to unqualified function names in a non global namespace context:

> For functions […], PHP will fall back to global functions […] if a namespaced function […] does not exist.

I.e. a call to the unqualified function name `file_get_contents()` in e.g. the namespace `foo` can be overridden by providing a `foo\file_get_contents()`.

---

I recently created the library [PHP-Mock](https://github.com/php-mock/php-mock) which provides mocks for some non deterministic PHP functions like `time()`.