# PHP override_function without the use of APD?

Tags: php, gcc, compiler-construction

I'm trying to use override_function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php
from

http://pecl.php.net/package/apd
but APD hasn't been updated since 2004 and no longer installs via PECL.

I tried to compile it using the patch listed in 
http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=16780&edit=2

It was successful but the compile directive I'm using

`sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/phpize CFLAGS='-O2 -arch i386 -arch ppc -g -Os' LDFLAGS='-O2 -arch i386 -arch ppc ' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -arch i386 -arch ppc -g -Os'`

is creating a file with 64 bit architecture

```
 /tmp/apd/apd-1.0.1: file modules/apd.so 
  modules/apd.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64`
```

I've no idea why it's not working - but this has become a super long detour for a function I might just be able to override some other way.

```
  override_function('header', '$a', 'echo $a;');
```

Comment: have you not thought about using namespaces to encapsulate your functions

Comment: sadly, the production version of PHP is pre namespaces.  I'm running PHPUnit to execute unit tests against code that's going to go into production. Maybe adding an SO is just as bad - but I thought staying away from namespace was the safest way to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possibility is using [`runkit_function_redefine`](https://www.php.net/runkit_function_redefine).

Note, that the [PECL version](http://pecl.php.net/package/runkit) of runkit is from 2006, while there's a newer version on [github](https://github.com/zenovich/runkit/).

See also: [Redefine Built in PHP Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326835/redefine-built-in-php-functions)

Comment: looks lovely!  :) if I take the one off git, does it compile the same way?  `phpize -> configure -> make`  ?

Comment: I have no idea, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: Get the latest apd source from the PECL homepage. Patch it with the mentioned [patch](http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=16780&edit=2), phpize, make, make test, make install. And follow the [instructions](http://at.php.net/manual/en/apd.installation.php) to load the module.

$ file apd-1.0.1/module/apd.so:

```
apd-1.0.1/modules/apd.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

php -v gives me:

```
PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: May  2 2011 23:18:30) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Advanced PHP Debugger (APD) v1.0.1, , by George Schlossnagle
```