# Override a default php function ? (eval)

Tags: php

we can simply override a default php function by using the following code :

```
namespace blarg;
function time() {
  echo "test !";
}
time();
```

but ! is it possible to override the "eval" functon ?

```
namespace blarg;
function eval() {
echo "test !";
}
eval();
```

?

### thanks in advance

According to the answeres :

1. eval() is a language construct and not a function, we can't override it 
   2.Im not really overriding the time() function in my example. I'm just creating a blarg\time() function

---

I understood 
**BUT**
Actually i'm writtin sumting like a debugger and i need to change the default behaviour of php functons or some language construct (e.g eval)
Is there anyway to do this ?
Is it possible to change the php source and compile it ? (Is there any specific file to edit ?)

Comment: **eval()** is a language construct and not a function, you can't override it.

Comment: And you're not really overriding the time() function in your example. You're just creating a `blarg\time()` function.

Comment: Here is the similar SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326835/redefine-built-in-php-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namespace blarg;
function time() {
  echo "test !";
}
time();
```

This does not override the builtin `time()` function. What this does is create the function `blarg\time()` -- that is, both `time()` and `blarg\time()` exist and can be called, so never was `time()` overridden.

When you call `time()` in the `blarg` namespace, both the builtin `time()` and local `blarg\time()` functions are candidates to be called; however, PHP will disambiguate by always calling the most local name, which in this case is `blarg\time()`.

Now, if we ask if it is possible to introduce a function locally named `eval()`, the answer is no, because `eval` is a reserved word in the PHP language because of its special meaning -- referred to as a language construct. Other examples of the same nature are `isset`, `empty`, `include`, and `require`.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** Because this is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using variable functions [Manual](http://php.net/eval)

So, it can't be overriden as echo/php/include too

Comment: This, +1. Note about the `include` portion however, you can of course override the `file://` protocol with a stream wrapper of your own...