# Catch mysql_query function in PHP to create custom trigger

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, analytics

I have huge project in PHP, which is using `mysql_connect` function in lots of files.
My goal is to detect how many times mysql_connect was triggered from PHP. (from this project).

Idea is to not modify existing project files and create some parallel function (trigger) which will run only when this project will call `mysql_connect` in PHP.

Is there any way to configure PHP to create some trigger on `mysql_connect`? I mean, when PHP will call `mysql_connect`, this trigger must detect this and parallely run some another script, which will do counting or other stuff.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php Override it and log that stuff! (Check out the first user contributed example)

Comment: Or try using namespaces for this job > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932177/override-a-default-php-function-eval

Comment: You might be able to use the logging capabilities of the Suhosin patch for this. Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

There is no trigger event that is fired on new connections (at least none listed here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html)

But you can ask MySQL directly how many connections have been attempted (successful or not)

```
show status like 'Connections'
```

(See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections for more status information)

Maybe it also helps you to know that each connection gets a unique connection id which you can retrieve via

```
SELECT connection_id()
```

So if you have a table that is queried by each script your trigger could react to actions on that table, get the connection id of the active connection and write it somewhere if it has not been logged before.

Beware that the enumeration of connections starts at the beginning if the MySQL server is restarted. This also applies to MySQLs internal connection count which you can retrieve with `show status`.

But as already mentioned, I would also strongly consider to solve this problem on the side of PHP.

Comment: I don't think the question is asking about mySQL triggers. I think he's asking about triggering a script when PHP does something (ie connect to the DB). The choice of the the word 'trigger' in the question is unfortunate given the existence of a mySQL feature with the same name, but reading the question it's fairly clear that isn't what he wants.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you are right and I was mislead by the wrong terminology.