# Creating a wrapper for a function with same name

Tags: php, function, overriding

I saw a function in cakephp-1.2 core files.

```
/**
* Convenience method for header()
*
* @param string $status
* @return void
* @access public
*/
function header($status) {
  header($status);
}
```

see https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.2/cake/libs/controller/controller.php#LC638

What may the reason they are redefining the function with same name?
Will it work? I think the *header* function will create infinite recursion.
I don't know how to check whether it creates infinite recursion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the top of the code, line 40:

```
class Controller extends Object {
```

That method is `Controller::header`, so does not override `header`. You can't "override" PHP functions: you'll simply get an error.

Comment: More precisely, it does not *conflict* with `header`.

Comment: This is the right answer, but it is possible override functions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326835/redefine-built-in-php-functions

Comment: Ok, it's not possible to override functions with a standard installation of PHP...