# Make PHP includes print their file location while in `dev` mode

Tags: php, include, require, require-once, php-include

We've all seen websites with code like this:

```
<!-- begin /a4/includes/nav_include.php -->
  <div ... >
<!-- end /a4/includes/nav_include.php -->
```

This is sloppy and annoying, but I understand the need to be able to figure out what file is responsible for the source code you're seeing. What I'd prefer is a way to make all `include`d and `require`d files automatically spit this info out, but only when in a toggleable dev mode.

Obviously, I could do something like this:

```
<?php
  if($devmode){ echo "<!-- begin /a4/include/snav_include.php -->"; }  
  include("/a4/includesnav_include.php");
  if($devmode){ echo "<!-- end /a4/includes/nav_include.php -->"; }  
?>
```

But that just becomes annoying and sloppy on a whole other level. I'd prefer to get the best of both worlds, where I have the functionality of above but can still write my includes like this:

```
<?php include("/a4/includes/nav_include.php"); ?>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: When you realize that all the output must be done in one place only - this technique becomes pointless. So: you only need that if you do perform output in multiple places.

Comment: What does it mean to perform output?

Comment: Running `echo`, `print`, or any other function that produces output.

Comment: This is one of the primary reasons to go (H)MVC.

Comment: Ah. Well maybe once I get everyone here to stop creating table based layouts we can work on that.

Comment: HTML details have nothing to do with it actually. Your HTML may be as terrible as hell, but with nice php that produces it.

Comment: The point is that I'm working with people of various skill levels and there are a lot of very old habits that are not going to be easy to get them to break. Completely changing the way PHP is used is not going to happen here until all the old dogs retire.

Comment: Wrap those 3 lines in a function then

Comment: Are you wanting to [redefine `include()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326835/redefine-built-in-php-functions)?