# Wordpress child theme: override functions

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

In my parent Theme I've a function without the initial statement:

```
if (!function_exists(... etc...
```

How can I replace it with a function with the same name in my child theme?
If I create the function into my functions.php it gives me an error due to the fact that there are two functions with the same name.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725194/php-override-existing-function

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working for me:

```
function fileExistsInChildTheme($file_path){
    $file_directory = get_template_directory();
    if(file_exists($file_directory . "-child" . $file_path)){
        return $file_directory .= "-child" . $file_path;
    }
    return $file_directory .= $file_path;
}

require ( fileExistsInChildTheme('/includes/functions.php') );
require ( fileExistsInChildTheme('/includes/theme-options.php') );
require ( fileExistsInChildTheme('/includes/hooks.php') );
require ( fileExistsInChildTheme('/includes/version.php') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Child theme function.php file is loaded **before** the parent theme functions file, therefore you shouldn't get fatal error for re-declaring the function in the child theme. That's why your parent theme is using the `function_exists` check.

Maybe you're declaring the function in the child theme after a hook(e.g. init)?

Here is the codex documentation about this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Referencing_.2F_Including_Files_in_Your_Child_Theme

Comment: The problem is that for this function, the parent theme is not using function_exists check

Comment: Oh, I misread the "without" word -- sorry about the bad comment. The only other idea I have is to perform `remove_action` or `remove_filter` for that function and then hook another function on it's place. Not sure if this is applicable for your case though.

Comment: I know, thank you the same. I think I've to go for another way by creating a new function.

Answer (score 0):

i think if you add same name of function then it take from child theme function then it take from parent.

For ex.

**Child Theme**

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'function_name' ) ) {
  function function_name(){
    echo 'This is child theme';
  }
}
```

**Parent Theme**

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'function_name' ) ) {
  function function_name(){
    echo 'This is parent theme';
  }
}
```

Comment: @Avionicom can you please check my answer