# Redefining PHP function in PHP CLI interpreter

Tags: php, command-line-interface

When using the PHP CLI interpreter, **how might one redefine a function** that has a bug. For instance, the original function declaration here lacks a newline character and I would like to fix it:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > function drinkBeer(){
php {     echo "Carlsburg";
php { }
php > 
php > drinkBeer();
Carlsburgphp > 
php > 
php > function drinkBeer(){
php {     echo "Carlsburg" . PHP_EOL;
php { }
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drinkBeer() (previously declared in php shell code:2) in php shell code on line 3
php >
```

We have seen similar questions asking [how to redefine a function when running a PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640958/redefining-php-function) however **none of the similar questions address the issue of redefining functions on the PHP CLI interpreter.**

For instance, the Python interpreter allows this:

```
$ python3

>>> def drinkBeer():
...  print('Carlsburg')
... 
>>> drinkBeer()
Carlsburg
>>>
>>> def drinkBeer():
...  print("You've had enough!")
... 
>>> drinkBeer()
You've had enough!
>>>
```

Comment: Why should the interpreter matter? The language is the same, you simply don't have access to HTTP stuff like `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

Comment: If you have the potential to make mistakes then dont use the `-a` option. Save the php code into a file eg `test.php` and run it like this `php test.php`.

Comment: Use UP and DOWN arrows to edit the previously inserted code.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Considering that the potential to make mistakes is `E = 1/2 m v^2` and I have too much `m`, I make many mistakes!

Comment: We all do. I was not suggesting it was just you that makes mistakes, only that its easier to fix them if you dont have to code 100% script every time we do!

Comment: Notice how this question implicitly demonstrates the readability advantage of Python.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using PHP 5.3 or newer you can do the following

```
$func = function(){ echo "Foo"; };
$func(); //to execute
$func = function(){ echo "Bar"; };
$func(); // will echo Bar
```

Comment: Thank you Hazem! Though it does not resolve the issue, you do provide a creative workaround.

Comment: This really helps when using PHP in CLI mode

Answer (score -2):

See this for function oriented programming
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php

Form object oriented, just declare function in child class and use it!

Hope it was helpfull...

Good luck!