# Overwrite php builtin functions?

Tags: php

How to overwrite php default/builtin functions like gethostname(), die() etc..?

if we call a php function gethostname like `echo gethostname();` it will return localhost or whatever the host of the machine is. Instead of that, I want to pass hostname as host1.

I want to pass a custom host name whenever gethostname is called.

Comment: Download the PHP source code written in C, make changes you need, compile, done.

Comment: what type of C source code?

Comment: https://github.com/php/php-src

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redefining PHP function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640958/redefining-php-function)

Comment: http://php.net/get/php-7.2.6.tar.xz/from/this/mirror

Comment: Also note that you would need to repeat this process every time a new PHP version is released. This sounds like an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/) though.

Comment: It's probably **way** easier to just rename your host in Apache's httpd-vhosts.conf file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the function and write the functionality on your own:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php