# How can I redeclare, overwrite or rename a function in PHP4?

Tags: php, function, php4

I am looking for a way to redeclare, overwrite or rename a function in PHP4, in order to perform a unittest on a class that makes a call to another function. I want this function to be a test function instead.

I have several constraints:

- It has to work for PHP4.
- It has to work right out-of-the-box WITHOUT installing something else. (No adp or whatever).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620659/is-it-possible-to-overwrite-a-function-in-php

Answer (score 2):

Technically, it is possible using the [`override_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) or [`rename_function()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php) functions.

That's not a very clean way to handle it though, and instead I'd recommend that you update your class to allow you to redirect the call somewhere else.

For example, you can change this:

```
class MyClass {
    public function doSomething() {
        ...
        do_complex_calc();
        ...
    }
}
```

To something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public $calc_helper = 'do_complex_calc';
    public function doSomething() {
        ...
        $helper = $this->calc_helper;
        $helper();
        ...
    }
}

$x = new MyClass();
$x->calc_helper = 'another_func_for_testing';
$x->doSomething();
```

That can be cleaned up even more, but it shows the general idea. For example, I wouldn't recommend leaving the `$calc_helper` variable as public - I'd implement some sort of a method to let you change it instead.

Comment: Yes exactly, I got the same idea. This might even work for my task. Thanks

Comment: @Alex I just updated my answer to reflect the fact that it **is** possible, although I'd still recommend the way I originally described.

Answer (score 0):

for overwriting the function you can check  if function exits using `function_exists` but you can redeclare the function

```
if (!function_exists('function_name')) {
    // ... proceed to declare your function
}
```