# how to run your own delete-function with cakephp relations?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to delete my relations to via the $hasone.
But because I am using nested set modeling, i want to use my own delete 'function'.
How can i do this? CakePHP doesn't use my standard delete-function...

Thanks

Comment: You need to be more precise, and show some code what you have tried so far.

Comment: It's not about code. I am asking for a way to set my own delete-function when my application deletes relations

Comment: Are you trying to "break" (remove) your hasone relationship programmatically?  Like the "unbindmodel()" method? (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)  Or are you trying to override the delete method?

Comment: Yeah, i want to override the delete method. That's because my 'hasone' works with a nested set model. I have a complicated deletefunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to use `$this->Model->delete()` instead of going into your model and defining your own function like `myDelete()` (easier and probably a better idea...) - have a look at this post on polymorphism:

[Is it possible to overwrite a function in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620659/is-it-possible-to-overwrite-a-function-in-php)

On another note, Cake's functions are built to support cascading and modifying data through (often complex) model relationships, and you'd be better to work with it if you can.

[The manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html#delete) says this:

> You can hook custom logic into the delete process using the
>   beforeDelete and afterDelete callbacks present in both Models and
>   Behaviors.

I'd suggest you see what you can do with that before proceeding, or otherwise just define your own custom function in the model called `myDelete()` and use that.

Comment: Thanks. I found the relations between classes so they will delete if they depend on each other