# Is it possible to override the phpdoc return type of a global function?

Tags: php, laravel, phpdoc

I want to override the return type of the global [response function](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L755) as I've created a package which overrides the response class returned. A Service Provider is extending the response class which will be returned instead the default `\Illuminate\Http\Response`. This is all working and also recognized when generating IDE files via the [Laravel IDE helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper).

My problem is that only the **first call** of said function lists the extending class methods. Otherwise it lists methods from the phpdocs referenced `\Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory` Interface which is the one I want to override. My Interface is doing nothing but changing the return type to the response class of my package:

```
<?php

namespace My\Package;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory as BaseResponseFactory;

interface ResponseFactory extends BaseResponseFactory
{
    /**
     * Return a new response from the application.
     *
     * @param  string $content
     * @param  int $status
     * @param  array $headers
     *
     * @return \My\Package\Response
     */
    public function make($content = '', $status = 200, array $headers = []);

    /**
     * Return a new view response from the application.
     *
     * @param  string $view
     * @param  array $data
     * @param  int $status
     * @param  array $headers
     *
     * @return \My\Package\Response
     */
    public function view($view, $data = [], $status = 200, array $headers = []);
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Your custom response class could always extend Illuminate\Http\Response or the underlying Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response. But the point of an interface is that it gives you a fixed contract with other code that references the same interface. So, I think it's not a good idea to override methods in it.

Comment: As to the part of your question where you want to override the global response helper function: That should not be possible in the global namespace because the autloader loads Laravels helper functions before your own functions. But you could help yourself by redefining it in your own namespace, cf. Answer "Monkey patch in namespace php >= 5.3"  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620659/is-it-possible-to-overwrite-a-function-in-php

Comment: All I want to achieve is to simply have type hinting via the `response()` method, which points to the Laravel Contract, which states `\Illuminate\Http\Response` as return type in the phpdoc, rather than `\My\Package\Response`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way of achieving this would be to create a custom `app/helpers.php` file and in it override the whole Laravel `response` function with your desired @return type. If your using autoloading via Composer then adding

```
"autoload": {
    "files": ["app/helpers.php"]
}
```

will **not** work because Laravels helper functions are loaded first.
You must require the file manually in your `index.php` before `autoload.php`:

```
require __DIR__ .'/../app/helpers.php';
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

But be aware this will break your unit tests without tweaking phpunit.xml to include a custom bootstrap file!

Alternatively, there is a composer plugin (not tested) dealing with the priority problem: https://github.com/funkjedi/composer-include-files

In general, I think that doing this *just for IDE compliance* it's much too hacky & not an advantage at all.