# ubuntu php ignore ini_set("disply_error") and use only php.ini settings

Tags: php, ubuntu

How do i ignore all `ini_set("disply_error")` error on function call done via code and use only settings configured in php.ini file?

When I did a grep for `display_errors` it shows a large list which cannot be changed by manually, so is there any way to use only php.ini settings?

Answer (score 2):

In order to block changing of settings via `ini_set()` you need to overwrite or completely disable it.

## Disable ini_set

Put `ini_set` into the list of disabled functions in your `php.ini`:

```
disable_functions=ini_set
```

This has the disadvantage, that an error will be logged for every call to `ini_set()`.

## Overwrite ini_set

There are at least 2 ways to overwrite a function:

There is `overwrite_function()` ([Docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php)) which may or may not be installed in your system. The following snippet will silently disable `ini_set()`:

```
override_function('ini_set', '$a,$b', 'return true;');
```

And you can use namespaces to overwrite the behaviour:

```
<?php
    namespace MyNamespace {
        function ini_set($key, $value) 
        {
            return true;
        }

        ini_set('display_error', 'all');
```

In the above snippet, the function `ini_set` will resolve to `MyNamespace\ini_set` which overwrites the behaviour.

Source and Explanation for this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12128017/1392490