# How to override json_encode() functionality in php to replace null with ""

Tags: php

I have created total api's using php programming, for the output i used

```
json_encode($arr)
```

Now i want to print output by replacing null with "".

I have already completed 400+ webservices using json_encode($arr) to output, but i don't want to change to

can any body help

My Actual Array

```
$array=array("id" => "2",
"name" => "Test Name",
"address" => "83 Test Street",
"city" => "Test",
"phone" => "(123) 456-7890",
"video_thumb" => null,
"thumbnail" => null,
"description" => null);
```

echo json_encode($array);
//output:

```
{"id":"2",
"name":"Test Name",
"address":"83 Test Street","city":"Test","phone":"(123) 456-7890","video_thumb":null,
"thumbnail":null,
"description":null
}
```

Expecting output
//output

```
    {"id":"2","name":"Test Name",
"address":"83 Test Street",
"city":"Test","phone":"(123) 456-7890","video_thumb":"",
"thumbnail":"",
"description":""}
```

Comment: It’s never a good idea to override existing functions... just refactor your code and make that effort now before you get yourself in deeper problems ;-)

Comment: please explain more

Comment: overriding a system function is, based on the system in use, either very bad, bad, baaad practice or very not possible. the best way to go would be fixing the consuming code so it can correctly handle `null`, which is a valid JSON value. the second best way is to write your own wrapper function `json_encode_no_null` and replace all calls to json_encode. but don't be surprised when you accidentally break something that _needs_ `null` instead of `""`. if you still insist on overriding a function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3620748/5309228 - but you won't be happy with it.

Comment: that's not how you should solve your problem OP. Adjust the codes that uses the API instead.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
$array = array("id" => "2",
    "name" => "Test Name",
    "address" => "83 Test Street",
    "city" => "Test",
    "phone" => "(123) 456-7890",
    "video_thumb" => null,
    "thumbnail" => null,
    "description" => null
);

array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item){
    if(is_null($item)) $item = '';
});

echo json_encode($array);
```

Output

```
{"id":"2","name":"Test Name","address":"83 Test Street","city":"Test","phone":"(123) 456-7890","video_thumb":"","thumbnail":"","description":""}
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6729959bf4ae35f16e1e1e62bf73b4a791cb4b34)

If you have to call it 400 times, just wrap it in a function. Decorate the normal json_encode like this:

```
function my_json_encode($value,$options=0,$depth=512){
     array_walk_recursive($value, function(&$item){
        if(is_null($item)) $item = '';
     });

     return json_encode($value,$options,$depth);
}
```

This way you can access all the options and functionality of the normal method, but with one small change.  There is no "overriding" of core functions, no in the way you can override a class method.  Functions can be defined only one time, then they are set.

Comment: Same question for you too: are you sure that you understand the task? OP has ~400 places in the code with `json_encode`. Do you really suggest him edit it 400 times with the sample above?

Comment: It's trivial to wrap it in a function and call it 400 times, he calls json_encode 400 times, no?  Whats the difference between calling my_json_encode and that.

Comment: OP didn't ask how to replace `null` with `""` - I guess he can do it manually without your help. His question is "How to override json_encode() functionality". Read the title.

Comment: You cannot "override" a core PHP function, as you would override a class method.  You can only replace it for something else.

Comment: You CAN override a core PHP function, check Franz Gleichmann's answer first or visit directly http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php.

Comment: `overriding a system function is, based on the system in use, either very bad, bad, baaad practice or very not possible. the best way to go would be fixing the consuming code so it can correctly handle null, which is a valid JSON value. the second best way is to write your own wrapper function json_encode_no_null and replace all calls to json_encode`  I read it, how bout you read my answer.

Comment: And PS that's not an answer, it's a comment.  According to that "answer" what I suggest above is the second best way, the first makes to many assumptions to warrant an answer.  IE. I have no way to know if the OP can `he best way to go would be fixing the consuming code`  Therefore the only reasonable answer, is one in the line of what I provided :-)~

Comment: Also the issue with overriding the default functionality, is obviously, what if you actually want/need NULL in some other piece of JSON?  What do you do then.

Answer (score 0):

This code helped me to fix the problem without modifying all the services

```
ob_start(function($json) {
    function json_validator($data = NULL) {
        if (!empty($data)) {
            json_decode($data);
            return (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE);
        }

        return false;
    }

    if (json_validator($json)) {
        $response_arry = json_decode(str_replace('null', '""', $json));
        if (json_last_error_msg() == "Syntax error") {
            $response_arry = json_decode(str_replace('"null"', '""', $arr));
        }
        return json_encode($response_arry, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    } else {
        return ob_get_contents();
    }
});
```

Comment: _Try this_ answer are low-value here.  Always add an explanation of how your solution works and why it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use override_function to "modify" the json_encode function. Before calling this function it is possible to modify the array so that it satisfies an empty string rather than null.
You can try this:

```
rename_function('json_encode', 'override_json_encode' );
override_function("json_encode", '$array', 'return override_json_encode($array);' );


function override_json_encode($array){
    foreach ($array as &$value) {
        if ($value === null) 
             $value = "";
    }
return json_encode($array);
}
```

}

Comment: _Try this_ answer are low-value here.  Always add an explanation of how your solution works and why it is a good idea.

Comment: The idea is to use override_function to "modify" the json_encode function. Before calling this function it is possible to modify the array so that it satisfies an empty string rather than null. What do you think about it?

Comment: Your comment should be transferres to your answer as an [edit].

Answer (score -1):

oh, understand your mean. please view follow document:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.apd.php
rename_function and override_function

Comment: Oh sweet my -- NO.  Let's agree to not advise developers to needlessly hack at json strings with `preg_replace()`.  Find another way.