# Rename a specific symbol on library include, to avoid the fatal error 'Cannot redeclare <function>'

Tags: php, include, rename, symbols

Was trying to include a library in a WordPress plugin, and I got

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare js_escape() (previously declared in .../wp-includes/deprecated.php:2053) in .../plugins/my-plugin/lib/a-library.php on line ...
```

Is there a way to overcome the symbol clash, without tweaking the library source code ? I surely don't want to touch WordPress code, but the library is small enough to be patched, if it's the only way

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620659/is-it-possible-to-overwrite-a-function-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to overwrite a function in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620659/is-it-possible-to-overwrite-a-function-in-php)