# Changing the PHP core function strpos()? How to swap the parameters $haystack and $needle?

Tags: php

I run always into the problem that my logic mind says "I search **what** **where**" and I bet this is with most developers.

However, the string search function of PHP [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) says "I search **where** **what**" which is not intuitive.

> strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] ) : int

Question:

Is there any way to change (override) the core function?

Bonus questions (which are more directed to developers who work/ed on PHP):

A. What was the reason for the existing order of the parameters?

B. Is there any chance that the main PHP developers consider changing this in one of the future PHP versions? Or adding a modified version of the strpos() to the core.

Comment: The problem is if you change the order of the parameters - how would it know which is the needle string and which the haystack string.  I think it's just a case of getting used to it.  Writing your own version also has the chance of confusing other programmers as they may not know what you mean but know what the standard should do.

Comment: Please open different questions for different questions. Additionally, the first question has been answered on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620659/is-it-possible-to-overwrite-a-function-in-php - the other questions should be target to PHP developers directly, for example on a developer mailing list. But as changing the order of arguments would break all existing usages, I'd assume that this has no chance

Comment: you can override the function

Comment: ... or just not use it - I honestly can't remember the last time I used `strpos()`

Comment: _"Is there any chance that the main PHP developers consider changing this"_ - How would we know that? However, I don't see it as likely since that would completely break backwards compatibility, causing more harm than good.

Comment: no luck, [php named function parameters](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params) is asleep...

Comment: A: ‍♂️ It is what it is because someone decided on it once and it's too late to change it now, because… B: Changing it now will break every piece of existing code out there using this function, so… no.

Comment: Your best course of action is to define your own `function offset_of_a_in_b($needle, $haystack, $offset = 0) { return strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset); }`. It's a sufficiently distinct name to not cause confusion to anyone, and it works fine alongside existing code.

Comment: @deceze ... I suspect somebody decided on the order once, in `C` (`strstr`) back in the 1970s and PHP just went with that ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can override build-in function by something like this:

```
<?php
   rename_function('strpos', 'strpos_old');
   override_function('strpos', '$a,$b,$c', 'return strpos_new($a,$b,$c);');
   function strpos_new($a,$b,$c){
      return strpos_old($b,$a,$c);  
   }
?>
```

PS. It needs `PECL apd >= 0.2`.

Comment: Just… please don't do this, since it will break every other piece of code using `strpos`.

Comment: That is what op wanted?

Comment: Just because OP wanted it doesn't mean it's a good idea to do it.

Comment: I'm assuming that if he got 8,650 points on SO, he knows what he is doing

Comment: That's the correct technical answer on my question. I haven't asked if it breaks previous code or not. I am aware of such issues, of course.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206094/discussion-on-answer-by-flash-thunder-changing-the-php-core-function-strpos-h).