# Is it possible to invalidate the php utf8_encode / decode function?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

My website has been running for a long time.
Currently upgraded to php 5.6 and maria db 10.1.44.
The utf8_encode function was used in a lot of php code.
But now I have to remove it so the characters are output correctly.
However, I can't edit a lot of php code ... Is there a way to invalidate the utf8_encode function?
Or is it possible to override the php core function?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could do so by making some changes in the `php.ini` file as

[Disable PHP Functions](https://www.easycgi.com/help/article/scripting-how-to-disable-php-functions)

Answer (score 1):

You [could override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620659/is-it-possible-to-overwrite-a-function-in-php) utf8_encode() with [`function_override()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) but I can not recommend it.

Instead, you better fix the existing code yourself. When you use an IDE like [Eclipse PDT](https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/), you can do a global search in all files and folders, and remove the calls to [`utf8_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) rather quickly.

While [PHP 5.6's default encoding](https://www.saotn.org/php-56-default_charset-change-may-break-html-output/) has been changed to [UTF-8](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/), that version is already end-of-life: https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php. After moving up to 5.6, consider [migrating](https://www.php.net/migration74) your code to PHP 7.2 at least.