# How to redefine a function in php?

Tags: php, function, redefinition

Now i'm stuck with file_exists() function. My project is built from repositories, one is symlinked as a DocRoot, others are available to php interpreter via include_path. But the default file_exists() cannot look at the files are placed somewhere under include_path, so i need or somehow redefine this func with a wrapper or to write my own, include it in other modules and replace all matches of this func in the directory tree. It's possible, but is not good and is not clear for developers.

I've already seen pecl-apd (2008) and pecl-runkit (2007), but there are no more such pecls among the others in my gentoo repository or the overlays. So, how to redefine a function in a modern way?

**== upd ===**

Ok. Let's go deeper.

Assume we have `/home/me/repos/` directory, where our git modules are placed and a virtual host `/var/srv/domain.com`, where it all is assembled

```
repos_
      \_site_root_
                  \_.git
                   \_file1
       \_module1_
                 \_.git
                  \_we_need_this_file_too
        \_module2_
                  \_.git
domain.com_
           \_htdocs –> ~/repos/site_root
            \_tmp
```

so we need to somehow include folders with modules 1 and 2 into the project. Then adding path to ~/repos to php include_path via vhost config

```
php_admin_value include_path ".:/home/me/repos"
```

Now php can

```
include ('module1/we_need_this_file_too');
```

from my repos directory. but when it tries to check the file before including with file_exists(), it fails, because those directories **are still closed for file_exists().** This is the problem.

Now i've found a workaround with absolute paths, anyway i'd have to create a personal config in my project. I also though about to chdir() into `/home/me/repos/` when it needs to (and describing `<Directory>` section in vhost), but it was bad idea.

Comment: Can you clarify the question please. I dont understand what you are trying to do with file_exists. And there might be a better solution than redefining the function.

Comment: I guess you already thought about creating symlinks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redefining PHP function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640958/redefining-php-function)

Comment: ...[Php redefine Class Methods OR Class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/137006/), [Is it possible to replace a function in php (such as mail) and make it do something else?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1837184/), [Is it possible to replace (monkeypatch) PHP functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/530649/)

Answer (score 2):

From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

> PHP does not support function overloading, nor is it possible to undefine or redefine previously-declared functions.

Well, you may, as you already mentioned, if you install the [runkit extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/runkit.installation.php) and use [runkit_function_redefine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php) or if you install [APD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apd.installation.php) and use [override_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php).

Comment: OP already said he knows runkit and apd, so this is not helpful. Besides, if that was the answer, then the question would be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326835/redefine-built-in-php-functions and several others asking the same.

Comment: It's helpful enough in pointing out that, without using runkit, it's unlikely to be possible.

Comment: @David I'd argue if the OP already found runkit and apd, OP knows that it's not possible

Comment: @Gordon: the answer is no, and for completeness I mentioned the extension. Anyhow, I changed it to note the question already mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

I working on library for function redefining in php5.3

Source: https://github.com/Bubujka/bu.defun

Exampls: http://defun.bubujka.org/doc.html

Simple redefining:

```
<?php
def('name', function(){ 
    echo "Waserd"; 
});
name();
echo "\n";

def('name', function(){ 
    echo "Bubujka"; 
});
name();

---

Waserd
Bubujka
```