# php - modify standard function

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redefine Built in PHP Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326835/redefine-built-in-php-functions)

I need to override one of the standard functions of php. in javascript, I would have done it this way:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.alert = function(str) {
            document.write(str);
        }
        alert("hello");
    </script>
```

whether it is possible to do this in php?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redefine Built in PHP Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2326835/), [How to redefine a function in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6925736/), [Redefining PHP function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2640958/), [Is it possible to overwrite a function in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3620659/)

Comment: What particular PHP function are you trying to "override"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: ... [Is it possible to replace (monkeypatch) PHP functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/530649/), [Is it possible to replace a function in php (such as mail) and make it do something else?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1837184/), [Php redefine Class Methods OR Class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/137006/)

Answer (score 1):

With the [Advanced PHP Debugger](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apd.php) PECL extension it is.  See the [`override_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) docs.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is a PHP module that can do that, but generally no.

[override_function of the APD module](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php)