# Cannot redeclare a function previously declared

Tags: php, mysql, function, redeclare

After I have instaled in my site one script, I have an error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare ae_detect_ie() (previously declared in /home/xdesign/public_html/Powerful/config.php:24) in /home/xdesign/public_html/Powerful/config.php on line 29
```

This is the line:

```
function ae_detect_ie()
{
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && 
    (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I don't understand what I did wrong!

The site: http://fbswapes.com

The same script is working in another host.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620659/is-it-possible-to-overwrite-a-function-in-php) & [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837184/is-it-possible-to-replace-a-function-in-php-such-as-mail-and-make-it-do-someth) out.

Comment: Wrap it with `! function_exists()` as a quick and dirty hack?

Comment: Or use `include_once()` to prevent loading your config file twice.

Comment: This give me error..  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/xdesign/public_html/Powerful/config.php on line 22

Comment: This generally happens when you try to define an already defined function. Use **include_once**.

Answer (score 8):

Simpily you have declared a function twice.. Example:

**Global.Fun.php**

```
<?php

      function Do_Something (){
       echo "This Does Something";
      }
?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
   include "Global.Fun.php";
   function Do_Something($Arg){
    echo "Argument Supplied".$Arg;
   }
?>
```

Notice, I have declared the same function twice, one in my `global.fun.php` page and again in the `index.php` page..

If you are in doubt that a function is currently set:

```
if (function_exists('Do_Something')){
   echo "Function Exists"; 
}else{
   echo "Function Not Found, This name Can be used!";
}
```

Comment: Done new si working, but i have this error:

    Warning: mysql_fetch_array() [function.mysql-fetch-array]: The result type should be either MYSQL_NUM, MYSQL_ASSOC or MYSQL_BOTH. in /home/xdesign/public_html/Powerful/header.php on line 885

In the line 885 , I have:


 
    885    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, $numass)) {
    886        array_push($got, $row);
    887 }

Comment: @CindySeoLine The error being..?

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() [function.mysql-fetch-array]: The result type should be either MYSQL_NUM, MYSQL_ASSOC or MYSQL_BOTH. in /home/xdesign/public_html/Powerful/header.php on line 885 In the line 885

Comment: @CindySeoLine Please post the code to your question.

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, $numass)) {

Comment: @CindySeoLine As you have already asked another question with this error message I will not reply here. Furthermore, if this has resolved your initial problem with the function redeclaration issue. Then mark this as the answer by clicking the green tick underneath the votes