# Can we hook PHP mail() function

Tags: php

Can we hook PHP mail() function, Like when the mail function call we call our function before sending emails. I need to perform some action between mail function calling and sending.

Comment: can you give some example??

Comment: If you abstract your mail dependency behind a custom object then internally that object can perform any pre- and post- tasks needed where it wraps the call to `mail()`.

Comment: No, you can't override built-in functions.

Comment: I do not have any example. because it is a simple when we call mail() function. I need to register some hook.. or extend core mail() function's functionality. so it will work like after calling and before sending my register hook should be call.

Comment: Marc B:- so any other way i can do like that some server level script.

Comment: write your own function, or use an external library like Swiftmailer or PHPMailer, neither of which have to use mail() to actually send mail.

Comment: This question is perfectly clear and it was closed for no good reason. I am here because I want to do the exact same thing.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837184/is-it-possible-to-replace-a-function-in-php-such-as-mail-and-make-it-do-someth

Answer (score 3):

David's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101300/can-we-hook-php-mail-function#comment29950659_20101300) provides the best advice:

> If you abstract your mail dependency behind a custom object then internally that object can perform any pre- and post- tasks needed where it wraps the call to mail()

However, if you choose not to follow that route, you can rename and replace the `mail()` function

```
rename_function('mail', 'new_mail');
override_function('mail', '$string', 'return override_mail($string);');

function override_mail($string){
    return new_mail($string);  
}
```

See further information and comments here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php . Note that `rename_function` and `override_function` are intended for debugging use, and are provided by the [Advanced PVP Debugger](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.apd.php) package.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, create your own function that has the same parameters as mail() and call mail() at the end of your function code. You can call it like xmail($reciever, $subject, $msg, $headers) and instead of using mail(), you are using your own function.

```
function xmail($reciever, $subject, $msg, $headers){
    //Do stuff
    mail($reciever, $subject, $msg, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at APD [override_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php).

Comment: [To hook PHP mail function globally, this tutorial provides the answer](https://www.inforepublic.org/how-to-hook-php-mail-function/)

Comment: That tutorial does *not* provide an answer, it provides an *alternative* that is only feasible if you have edit rights to `php.ini`, which I don't.