# Change default PHP function output

Tags: php, function

Wonder if there's some way to wrap PHP **default function** response in another function or prepend and postpend function response with strings. 
I wan tto do it without creating custom function, but instead changing default function output e.g. add  tag around **var_dump()** output.

```
$my_var = "Hello World!";
var_dump($my_var);
```

Outputs `Hello World!`

I want

```
$my_var = "Hello World!";
var_dump($my_var);
```

Outputs `<strong>Hello World!</strong>`

I am not interested in creating and calling custom function to do this, instead i want modify **var_dump()** output.

**EDIT:** I need native solution without installing PHP extensions

Comment: No, PHP offers no way of "overloading" functions in the standard language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to replace a function in php (such as mail) and make it do something else?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837184/is-it-possible-to-replace-a-function-in-php-such-as-mail-and-make-it-do-someth); or [Redefining PHP functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640958/redefining-php-function); or [Is it possible to replace (monkeypatch) PHP functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530649/is-it-possible-to-replace-monkeypatch-php-functions?lq=1) or many others found by a quick search.

Comment: As pointed out in some of the existing answers, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18120190/157957, you can define a function of the same name in a namespace, e.g. `namespace Awesome { function var_dump() { ... }`, then with `use Awesome;` at the top of each file, PHP will see any call to `var_dump($foo);` as actually meaning `Awesome\var_dump($foo);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `runkit_function_rename` if you install the [`runkit` PECL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php).

You will have to place some code before any var_dumps are called but you can create your own var_dump after renaming the existing var_dump.

I do think this is a terrible idea though, and you've much better off writing your own function as a wrapper for var_dump and refactoring your code to use your new function.

Otherwise, what you wish to do is not possible with a native PHP installation.

Comment: Thanks, but i need native solution if there's any.

Comment: Then it's not possible I'm sorry.

Comment: @RomanToasov This is the best answer you're going to get, sorry. The answer to "can this be done without an extension?" is simply "no".

Comment: There should be way because i successfully used PECL extensions locally without installation to server, just downloaded and included in my project using `require_once()` with slight modification of paths. Perhaps if i look at it source i can find how they doing this.

Comment: @RomanToasov A PECL extension is compiled C code that interacts with the internals of the language; you cannot simply include it or replicate it in PHP code.

Comment: @RomanToasov Feel free to look at the source, though. In the case of `runkit_function_redefine`, it's here: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PECL/runkit/runkit_functions.c#638

Comment: Yeah i see this one is in C other one i used was just bunch of PHP classes. Never mind then i will just create custom function with var_dumpz(); or smth.