# PHP automatically log the output of exec()

Tags: php, shell, logging, exec

We have an inside tool in my workplace where a lot of colleagues create short php scripts. Almost every script contains a call of exec() function to run python scripts.

I would like to log everything that these exec calls return into files, but I cannot tell colleagues to save the return value.

Can I somehow override exec or are there any other solutions to save everything that happens in shell?

Comment: Quick and dirty: Create a wrapper function for `exec`, then search/replace all `exec` with that function.

Comment: That would be the easiest way I think, but I cannot colleagues to create the new scripts with the new function.

Comment: I had a look around, but only found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837184/is-it-possible-to-replace-a-function-in-php-such-as-mail-and-make-it-do-someth so in effect you can override that function.