# dokuwiki - bypass core or template function from template

Tags: php, dokuwiki

I would like to bypass core and plugin functions to customize them.
I didn't succeed to do it from template.

I try to add into my tpl_functions.php something like:

```
if (!function_exists('html_buildlist')) {
  function html_buildlist($data,$class,$func,$lifunc='html_li_default',$forcewrapper=false){
   // etc.
  }
}
```

My first idea is to check if the page has been visited and then customize the indexmenu plugin.

For example, i make this function to check if a page has been visited:

```
function wt__pagevisited($id){

  if ($id == null) {
    global $INFO;
    $id = $INFO['id'];
  }

  // get cookie session info
  $crumbs = isset($_SESSION[DOKU_COOKIE]['bc']) ? $_SESSION[DOKU_COOKIE]['bc'] : array();

  // check ID into breadcrumb
   if( array_key_exists($id,$crumbs) ) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Jean-baptiste

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking has nothing to do with DokuWiki. You want to replace PHP functions. That's not possible without the help of certain PHP extensions. See [Is it possible to replace a function in php (such as mail) and make it do something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837184/is-it-possible-to-replace-a-function-in-php-such-as-mail-and-make-it-do-someth) for more info.

Comment: Thank you Andreas for your answer. I understand your answer. I was thinking about a way to bypass with a file for file system as we can find in some cms: file-A.php in the template bypass file-A.php in the plugin which bypass file-A.php in the core. So in order to customize plugins (indexmenu and bookcreator - i would like to rethink the way it is displayed - ) do you advise to hack the plugins as the best way?