# Can I wrap functions in PHP?

Tags: php, function, wrapper

I know this question sounds easy to answer, and I must have missed something somewhere, but after searching, I can't find an answer.  I only can find answers about wrapping functions in classes, but I would like to wrap functions themselves, such as `fopen`.

Why: This may sound strange, but I want to make a site builder in which you write code and it saves it on your account.  You should be able to write PHP, but of course you shouldn't delete or open server files, so I want to wrap functions so that I can first check if their `fopen`, `rmdir`, or similar functions are safe.

Comment: I don't understand the question, you can just put `fopen()` in a func like `myFopen()` that checks the input and output before returning. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @symlink: Yes, but then they can simply just use `fopen` and not `myFopen`, therefore making the attempt useless.

Comment: So you want to expose your own functions to them, but not give them access to the rest of PHP?

Comment: @symlink: Yes, precisely.  From JS, I thought something like `fopen=function(){if(safe){execute fopen;};`, but function wrapping made more sense.  In PHP I think/know you can't assign functions.

Comment: I think when you handle their input, you can just check to see if isn't one of your functions, and then execute one of your functions based on the input. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I think that's better ensured by the webserver running the code and/or the user setup of the machine underneath. That said, yes, some plugins intercept PHP native functions for e.g. metrics.

Comment: How are they entering the input? Are they typing it into a textarea and submitting a form?

Comment: @Mar: That looks interesting.  Let me try it.  Will let you know if it works

Comment: @Mar: That needs an APD (Advanced PHP Debugger).  Not very sure about if to and how to use it.

Comment: @symlink: Yes, let's say that they type into a text area and send a POST request to the server to save the code.

Comment: The reason you're struggling to find anything about this is that what you're asking for wouldn't normally be called "wrapping" - that would normally just mean a new function with a new name. What you seem to be asking for is a way to "replace", "shadow", or "over-ride" built-in functions.

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100538/how-to-overwrite-existing-php-functions-without-apd

Comment: @Mar: I'm going to use the namespace answer or [the whitelist approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66283970/14469685).  They seem to require the least setup, and won't be too complicated.

Comment: Another possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530649/is-it-possible-to-replace-monkeypatch-php-functions In fact, although I've posted an answer based on your comments, the actual text of this question doesn't say anything those three don't, so I'm going to go ahead and mark it duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frame challenge: if you did succeed in this, it would be **using a blacklist to achieve security**, which is **basically impossible to do effectively**. For every function you replace with a "safe" version, there will be ten you hadn't thought of that can be used in a malicious way.

Instead, you should either use a **whitelist** or a **sandbox**.

In a **whitelist** approach, you don't let the user enter normal PHP at all, but a special set of functionality that you've carefully picked to allow them to do what they need. That could be an actual subset of PHP that you parse with something like [nikic/php-parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser), a templating language like [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/), or a completely new language you write a simple parser for.

In a **sandbox** approach, you allow the user to enter full PHP, but you run it in an isolated environment where they can't affect your real server. Any access to the file system or network would only be accessing virtual resources, and if the process abuses CPU or memory resources, the entire sandbox can be terminated. See for instance [how the 3v4l.org site is hosted](https://3v4l.org/about).

Comment: OK, will think about it.  The whitelist approach seems the best to me.  Thanks!