# Pass methods to the class from other class

Tags: php, oop

Let's say we have index.php

```
class Foo_class extends FOOBAR
{
    function __construct()
    {
        require 'some_other_class.php';
        new Some_other_class;

        $this->say_hello();
    }
}
```

And some_other_class.php

```
class Some_other_class
{
    function say_hello()
    {
        echo "Wow, it works!";
    }
}
```

I want, that by including and calling a class `Some_other_class` in the `Foo_class` class, `Some_other_class` class would give `Foo_class` all of its methods. Is it possible by doing that and not extending? Of course my code will not work.

Comment: You should not use "OMG" in your classnames. Especially if its in an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP 5.4 comes with a concept of [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) which are basically what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to let `some_other_class` give its methods to `Foo_class`, you can also get all of its methods with `get_class_methods()`. Have a [look at the PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php).

So, in your case, you could do something like this:

```
class Foo_class extends FOOBAR
{

    private $classes = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->register('some_other_class.php');
        $this->say_hello();
    }

    function register($class) {
        require($class);
        $this->classes[$class] = array();
        $c = new $class;
        foreach(get_class_methods($class) as $method) {
            $this->classes[$class][] = $method;
        }
    }

    function __call($name, $arguments) {
        foreach($this->classes as $c_name => $c) {
            foreach($c as $method){
                if($method == $name)
                    call_user_func(array($c_name, $name), $arguments);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In other, more flexible languages, what you're asking for is called "monkey patching". It's adding (or switching) methods in classes at runtime without resorting to inheritance.

Unfortunately, [php won't let you do this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/530649/576139).

Answer (score 0):

How about using get instance method to invoke remote class method

```
class Foo_class extends FOOBAR
{
    function __construct()
    {
        require 'some_other_class.php';
        Some_other_class::getInstance()->say_hello();
    }
}
```

some_other_class.php

```
class Some_other_class
{

   private static $_selfInstace;

   public static function getInstance() 
    {
        if( !(self::$_selfInstace instanceof self) ) {
            self::$_selfInstace= new self();
        }
        return self::$_selfInstace;
    }

    function say_hello()
    {
        echo "Wow, it works!";
    }
}
```